# Load Java-Byte-Code at Runtime

Tags: java, classloader, bytecode

I got some java-byte-code (so compiled java-source) which is generated in my program. Now I want to load this byte-code into the currently running Java-VM and run a specific function. I'm not sure how to accomplish this, I digged a little bit into the Java Classloaders but found no straight way.

I found a solution which takes a class-file on the harddisk, but the bytecode I got is in a Byte-Array and I dont want to write it down to the disk but use it directly instead.

Thanks!

Comment: I think under this link you should find what you are looking for: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html Look at the last section "ClassLoader Load / Reload Example".

Comment: My question was somehow unclear: I haven't got a class-file but a byte-array and I want to load it directly. Thanks anyway!

Comment: And I'm pretty sure my link provided exactly that. At least I found this through it: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass(byte[], int, int)
Also you can obviously always save your byte-array to a temporary directory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to write a custom class loader that overloads the findClass method

```
public Class findClass(String name) {
    byte[] b = ... // get the bytes from wherever they are generated
    return defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a way to got, but there is no direct way without writing a custon ClassLoader?

Comment: at least none i have found so far

Answer (score 2):

If the byte code is not on the classpath of the running program, you can use URLClassLoader.  From http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/LoadClass.html

```
// Create a File object on the root of the directory containing the class file
File file = new File("c:\\myclasses\\");

try {
    // Convert File to a URL
    URL url = file.toURL();          // file:/c:/myclasses/
    URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

    // Create a new class loader with the directory
    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

    // Load in the class; MyClass.class should be located in
    // the directory file:/c:/myclasses/com/mycompany
    Class cls = cl.loadClass("com.mycompany.MyClass");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
}
```

Comment: My question was somehow unclear: I haven't got a class-file but a byte-array and I want to load it directly. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Feel free to edit your question to be more precise.  The code quoted works with class files ón the harddisk.