# Create Temporary Jar File

Tags: java, jar, jvm

Is it possible to create a .jar file which only exists in the JVM and load class files via a FileOutputStream in it, and then start it?

I need it for my Obfuscator.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174436/load-java-byte-code-at-runtime)

Comment: I've already tried this, thanks anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by "and then start it"? Do you need to generate executable jar?

Comment: Yeah but I don't want it to be saved anywere on the pc - it should only exist in the jvm